# Does redux confuse react detecting "controlled" components or am I doing this wrong?

Tags: reactjs, redux

The following code is getting the warning:

```
Warning: Filter is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Filter.js:

```
import React       from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  setFilter = (event) => {
    let v = event.target.value

    if (v.length === 0) v = null;

    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'SET_FILTER',
      filter: v
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
       <input id='filter' className='form-control' onChange={this.setFilter} value={this.props.state.filter} />
      </p>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    state: state
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    dispatch: dispatch
  }
}

Filter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filter)
export default Filter
```

I'm having trouble seeing how this different from the docs' example except that I'm using the redux state.

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

But I could be missing something...

Comment: I believe the value passed to `value` should never be `null`. Therefore `this.props.state.filter || ''` should be used. Also, you should really pass `props` to `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the `input` value to `null` or `undefined`.  That makes it think it is uncontrolled.  If you want to keep `null` as your value instead of `""`, then just change it as you pass it as a prop to input.  This should avoid the error:

```
<input id='filter'
  className='form-control'
  onChange={this.setFilter}
  value={this.props.state.filter || ""} // note the || ""
/>
```